# Spring aop pointcut expression to access method return type

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcuts

I have a service interface with many methods, all of which take a Request object and return a Response object. All request objects have a common ancestor and all response objects have a different common ancestor (which has a success flag and a message field).

Now I want to have an around aspect that checks permissions etc, performs the service call and returns a Response object with a failure code if anything fails. The problem is: I need to know what type of Response object to create. Is there a pointcut expression that gives me access to the return type? Something like this, perhaps?

```
@Around(value = "execution(public *"
    + " com.mycompany.MyService+.*(..))"
    + " && args(request)"
    + " && returning( returnType)" // something like this would be nice

, argNames = "request,returnType")
public Object handleServiceCall(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
    final Request request,
    final Class<? extends Response> returnType){ ... }
```

Comment: So you want to advise several methods with the same aspect, which sometimes needs to produce and return the response object without calling the service, and that response object must be of the proper subtype for the service method?

Comment: yup, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`JoinPoint`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html) mentions a `getSignature()` method, whose return type `Signature` has a sub interface [`MethodSignature`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/MethodSignature.html) you could try casting to, which has a method `getReturnType()`, which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I am aware of this. this is the way I am prepared to go if no better solution exists, but I would prefer a pointcut expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that check inside the around advice method(handleServiceCall() in your case)

```
Object actuals = pjp.proceed();
if(actuals instanceof MyResponse){
//TO:DO: Your code here
}
```

Comment: I know, but that won't help, because I won't always do pjp.proceed(). If my aspect decides that the user doesn't have the right to execute the service call, it will create a response object directly without proceeding.

Comment: Do not use '*' as the 'ret-type-pattern' in the pointcut expression. Instead use the actual return type of the method that you want to intercept.

Comment: no good: I want to intercept many different return types, and I want to know which one I have.