# How to use Spring AOP to run code before every call of service method in Servlet

Tags: servlets, spring-aop

I have some common code must be injected into `service` method of any servlet .

Thus, i build a mother servlet `SuperController` :

```
public class SuperController extends HttpServlet{
     private HttpServletRequest lastRequest ; 
     //........
     public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res){
          setLastRequest(req); // example of common code
     }
}
```

Then, all other servlets extends from this servlet .

```
public GalleryServlet extends SuperController{

      public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res){
           //instead of running here the common code , use AOP. 
           // Then , the other code
      }

}
```

I want to execute the common code ( i.e: `setLastRequest(req)`) using AOP , since `super.service(req,res)` raised `ERROR 405` .

## com.ControllerAspect.java

```
@Before("* com.SuperController+.service(..)")
public void doStuffBeforeService(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

### How to Use Spring AOP :

- Does this pointcut `* com.SuperController+.service(..)` includes `service` methods in all classes inherits from `com.SuperController` .
- How to access to arguments (req & res ) of service method inside  `doStuffBeforeService` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[HTTP 405](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)* means that the HTTP request method is not supported e.g. GET used for POST etc. Check your config / logs for supported method(s) and the one actually used.

To answer your other questions -

- Yes the pointcut `* com.SuperController+.service(..)` should include `service` method(s) in `com.SuperController` class hierarchy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2848161/1910582).
- Use `joinPoint.getArgs()` to access the [method arguments](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()).